# Printing PDF'S (Pdfium.Net) printer queue

Tags: c#, pdf

I am working on a print utility software for my company, Currently our ERP software doesn't allow batch printing of work instructions nor our drawings.

I made a piece of software that takes a exported CSV file of the employees dispatch and grabs all of the shop orders and puts a delimiter ";" between them, this way they can put it in our ERP and print all at once Simultaneously I grab the part number and go search our files for the drawing.

I'm using Pdfium.Net to render said drawing (which for some odd reason it draws it twice but offset) and then send it to the printer... Well this library doesn't support print queuing(at least that I know off). I can make a print dialogue, Does this count as a que?. I cant afford to test out and be wrong because it will cost our company greatly. Is there a better library, Am I missing a feature of the library with ancient documentation? Please be kind to me its my first piece of big software.

Thank you

I'm at a stand still because if my assertion that a print dialogue acts as a buffer is wrong it will shut down our print server making the VP madder then he already is.

Comment: I agree with you and I wish I could do that. To be short. The office guys only job is to make sure that when our ERP crashes they turn it back on. They don't use the software. No one is steering the ship when it comes to the ERP. So as a inventory guy who has a heart for software this is my best attempt.

Comment: The actual print function works, right now when it reads my big csv (30 records) it slams our print server. So normally you would just make a queue. But the library I'm using doesn't really have that. I can make a dialog and ask the user 1 by 1 . In my mind that counts as a buffer and I could even do await or some error handling. I just don't want to be wrong. But at this point I'm gonna have to work with support and say hey lets stress test it. and find the limits after hours